# Do tabstops work in a MFC CCheckListBox?

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, controls

I have a MFC CCheckListBox control working fine except Tab stops do not seem to work.  When I supply the control with text strings that include the tab character ASCII 9 the text remains without any space for the Tabs.

Does anyone know if you can use tabstops in a CCheckListBox? I have tried a lot of different things and when I **google I find same problem but no solutions**. I have "Use Tabstops" box checked in the ListBox resource properties. I also have the Has Strings: True and Owner Draw: is Fixed (if that's any help). Here is the initialisation code that I am using:

```
BOOL CDlgQuotePOReceive::OnInitDialog()
{    
    CDialog::OnInitDialog();

    VERIFY(((CCheckListBox *) this->GetDlgItem(IDC_LB_PO_DETAIL))->SetTabStops(10));

    // Then code to fill the listbox with string data that 
    // is working fine to get the data into the control.

    return TRUE;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple answer is no!

Reason: CCheckListBox ist just an owner draw list box. You can find the source code in the mfc. When the text is drawn the function just uses ExtTextOut and doesn't care about tab stops.

See implementation of CCheckListBox::DrawItem in VC\atlmfc\src\mfc\winctrl3.cpp

So the solution for you is also easy. Write your own class derived from CCheckedListBox and use your own DrawItem function. Also you have the source code of the current DrawItem function and you can easily use another text output function.

Comment: Thanks heaps! Not only answers my question in detail but steers me in the direction of a solution. Only thing: if so easy to implement then it is a pity Microsoft didn't do it in the first place.  See how I go...